# Adding UIView back to View

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I have multiple subviews in my main view controller, I am using a delete button to remove one subview at a time. I am trying to allow the user to bring back the view that was deleted, but the view is not coming back. Any thoughts? In Swift.

```
@IBOutlet var tornView: UIView!
var deleted = 1 

// Delete Button
    @IBAction func deleteViewButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if deleted == 1 {
            tornView.removeFromSuperview()
            deleted = 2
        }
    }

// Brings View to Screen 
@IBAction func showTornAnnotation(sender: AnyObject) {
        if toggleState == 1 {
            firstSlider.hidden = false
            tornView.hidden = false
            toggleState = 2
            if deleted == 2 {
                view.addSubview(tornView)
            }
        }
        else {
            firstSlider.hidden = true
            tornView.hidden = true
            toggleState = 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: @AnilVarghese The view is not coming back to the screen.

Comment: @FrankBoccia where do you set up your `tornView`?

Comment: Like position wise ? If not they appear due to the function above "showTornAnnotation"

Comment: How about, instead of adding/removing it from superview, just setting `view.hidden = true/false`?

Comment: @ConnorNeville Im trying to make annotations, Im trying to allow the user to populate the same view multiple times, by clicking a button one view appears,and if the button is clicked again, the same exact view appears so there is 2 of the same views on the screen. How can i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `IBOutlet` to be removed from the `superView` and get it `added` back then you should always use `strong` references to your `IBOutlet`. Being said you should also keep the position of the removed `view` so that you can use it when you are ready to add it back.

**Edit: Sample code**

```
@IBOutlet var customView: UIView!
var customViewFrame: CGRect?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}
@IBAction func remove(sender: AnyObject) {
    customViewFrame = customView.frame
    customView.removeFromSuperview()
}

@IBAction func add(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let rect = customViewFrame {
        customView = UIView.init(frame: rect)
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        view.addSubview(customView)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(customView)
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i keep the position?

Comment: I have updated the answer with sample code, please try it.

Comment: Thank you so much, is there anyway I can inherit the properties of the original view or no?